# Law of naturality for list Traversable instance

Tags: haskell

A Traversable instance must satisfy 3 laws: Naturality, Identity, Composition.
The naturality law states that:

> ```
> t . traverse f = traverse (t . f)
> ```

But for the following examples, this does not hold true.

**Example 1**

```
t (Just a) = Left a
f = Just 
s = "string"

\> t . traverse f $ s
  Left "string"
\> traverse (t . f) s 
  Left 's'
```

One might argue that `(Either a b)` is applicative in `b`, not in `a`, but still, this example disproves that the law of naturality is satisfied by the Traversable instance for `[]`.

**Example 2**

```
t (head : tail) = replicate 2 head
f = (:[])
s = "string"

\> t . traverse f $ s
  ["string", "string"]
\> traverse (t.f) s 
  ["string", "string", ...., "string"]
-- a list with 64 elements
-- equivalent to: replicate 64 "string"
```

This is due to the nature (behaviour) of list`s Applicative instance. It forms a Cartesian product between the lists.

So, for the `ZipList` datatype this law holds, because it's Applicative instance behaves differently (one could say 'properly' - from the point of view of `traverse` and `sequenceA` respecting their Naturality laws).

Could someone clarify to me what am I doing/ seeing wrong, so that I could understand why the Traversable instance for `[]` is law-abiding?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an explicit condition that `t` must be an applicative transformation. [Here's the full documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#g:20):

> #### Laws
>
> A definition of `traverse` must satisfy the following laws:
>
> **Naturality**
>
> `t . traverse f = traverse (t . f)` **for every applicative transformation `t`**
>
> [...]
>
> where an *applicative transformation* is a function
>
> ```
> t :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) => f a -> g a
> ```
>
> preserving the `Applicative` operations, i.e.
>
> ```
> t (pure x) = pure x
> t (f <*> x) = t f <*> t x
> ```
>
> [some emphasis added]

The `t` functions in your examples are not applicative transformations. They don't preserve `pure`:

```
t (pure x) = Left x /= Right x = pure x
```

```
t (pure x) = [x,x] /= [x] = pure x
```